# AFC - show files in comments

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to add feature to my website where users will be able upload files in comments.
I'm trying to do that using Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Some parts of job are done. I have upload option while writing comment and after submiting comment the file is visable via Wordpress administration.

Comment administration (file is visable at the bottom)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7GFF.jpg

Custom field settings
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8dEo.png

Code for frontend I'm using in comments template

```
<?php
  $cfile = get_field('comment_file');
  if( $cfile ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $cfile['url']; ?>"><?php echo $cfile['filename']; ?></a>
  <?php endif;
?>
```

The problem is - I can't see file in frontend part of website. Like there is no file(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$comment = get_comment(); // Here you can get single Comment array
$cfile = get_field('comment_file', $comment); // Then you need to pass Comment variable with get_field
if( $cfile ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $cfile['url']; ?>"><?php echo $cfile['filename']; ?></a>
<?php endif;
```

You can visit below link for Reference - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-comment/